# SRSS Report Builder SUM IIF from different datasets

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have two datasets in Report Builder 3.0 with a similar field and I want to put a SUM of the number occurrences of a particular value in that common field across both datasets.

I've got an expression I'm using for each individual dataset:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!caseorigin.Value = "mail",1,0))
```

and

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!cliorigin.Value = "mail",1,0))
```

But I can't seem to work out a way to sum the values from both datasets. I've tried:

```
=SUM(IIF((Fields!caseorigin.Value, "caseDS") = "mail",1,0)) + SUM(IIF((Fields!cliorigin.Value, "cliDS") = "mail",1,0))
```

Is there any way to make this work, or an alternative method?

Answer (score 2):

Just looks like a syntax error here; when specifying a scope it should like something like:

```
=Sum(Expression, Scope)
```

Applying this to your example:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!caseorigin.Value = "mail",1,0), "caseDS")
  + SUM(IIF(Fields!cliorigin.Value = "mail",1,0), "cliDS")
```

Should work for you.